# How can I reference a stack output value in serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am using `serverless deploy` to create a stack in cloudformation for my application. The stack includes a `lambda layer` which I can find it in the cloudformation `Ouptputs` tab. It has a row with a key as `CommonLambdaLayerQualifiedArn`, value is its ARN, `description` and `Export name` are empty.

In another stack, I am using below syntax to reference the lambda layer from the previous stack. It works fine but I don't understand why it works without exporting the lambda layer in the previous stack. Cloudformation support cross stack reference which is done by exporting a value. But in above stack, the `Export name` for the lambda layer is empty. How come it works without a cross stack reference? Is it a different way to import the reference?

```
...
layers:
      - ${cf:${opt:lambdaLayerStackName}.CommonLambdaLayerQualifiedArn}
...
```

Comment: Is the bucket reused for both stacks? maybe [serverless-layers](https://github.com/agutoli/serverless-layers/blob/master/src/package/Dependencies.js) is resolving the dependency based on the stack name and the cloudformation template of it

Comment: No they use different s3 buckets.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you used is not **importing** variables from another stack. According to the [doc](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-cloudformation-outputs), it is simply

> referencing CloudFormation stack output values as the source of your variables to use in your service

It's the same as retrieving the output values from cloudformation using AWS CLI.

Comment: Is the `reference` a feature for `serverless` or is it part of `cloudformation`?

Comment: I did try that but I found a little different between `reference` and `importing`. When I use `import`, it has a dependency between the stacks which means it stop me delete the stack which has other stacks dependent on it. With `reference`, I am able to delete the stack even with other dependencies. So I wonder are they really same?